# Swift UI overwhelmed by high-frequency @StateObject updates?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, grand-central-dispatch

**Scenario**

A simple SwiftUI `App` that consists of a `TabView` with two tabs. The `App` struct has a `@StateObject` property, which is being repeatedly and very quickly (30 times per second) updated by `simulateFastStateUpdate`.

In this example, `simulateFastStateUpdate` is not doing any useful work, but it closely resembles a real function that quickly updates the app's state. The function does some work on a background queue for a short interval of time and then schedules a state update on the main queue. For example, when using the camera API, the app might update the preview image as frequently as 30 times per second.

**Question**

When the app is running, the `TabView` does not respond to taps. It's permanently stuck on the first tab. Removing `liveController.message = "Nice"` line fixes the issue.

1. Why is `TabView` stuck?
2. Why is updating `@StateObject` causing this issue?
3. How to adapt this simple example, so that the `TabView` is not stuck?

```swift
import SwiftUI

class LiveController: ObservableObject {
    @Published var message = "Hello"
}

@main
struct LiveApp: App {
    @StateObject var liveController = LiveController()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabView() {
                Text(liveController.message)
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                    }
                Text("Tab 2")
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "2.circle")
                    }
            }
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                    simulateFastStateUpdate()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func simulateFastStateUpdate() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            liveController.message = "Nice"
        }
        
        // waits 33 ms ~ 30 updates per second
        usleep(33 * 1000)
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            simulateFastStateUpdate()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: using your code as is, works without any problems for me on macos 12.beta, xcode 13.beta, target ios 15 and macCatalyst.
Tested on iPhone ios15 and macos 12. Maybe your issue happens on older ios, macos. Are you using this in Preview?

Comment: @workingdog I tested this on iOS 14 with simulator and iPhone 11 Pro Max.

Answer (score 2):

You are blocking the main thread with these constant updates and the app is busy processing your UI updates and can't handle touch inputs (also received on the main thread).

Whatever creates this rapid event stream needs to be throttled. You can use Combine's `throttle` or `debounce` functionality to reduce the frequency of your UI updates.

Look at this sample, I added the class `UpdateEmittingComponent` producing updates with a `Timer`. This could be your background component updating rapidly.

In your `LiveController` I'm observing the result with Combine. There I added a `throttle` into the pipeline which will cause the `message` publisher to fiere once per second by dropping all in-between values.

Removing the `throttle` will end up in an unresponsive `TabView`.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

/// class simulating a component emitting constant events
class UpdateEmittingComponent: ObservableObject {
    @Published var result: String = ""
    
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        cancellable = Timer
            .publish(every: 0.00001, on: .main, in: .default)
            .autoconnect()
            .sink {
                [weak self] _ in
                self?.result = "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)"
            }
    }
}

class LiveController: ObservableObject {
    @Published var message = "Hello"
    
    @ObservedObject var updateEmitter = UpdateEmittingComponent()
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        updateEmitter
            .$result
            .throttle(for: .seconds(1),
                scheduler: RunLoop.main,
                latest: true
            )
            .assign(to: &$message)
    }
}

@main
struct LiveApp: App {
    @StateObject var liveController = LiveController()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabView() {
                Text(liveController.message)
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                    }
                Text("Tab 2")
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "2.circle")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: works without any problems without the throttle for me on macos 12.beta, xcode 13.beta, target ios 15 and macCatalyst. Tested on iPhone ios15 and macos 12.

Comment: Interesting, I have no input response on an iPhone 7 test device running iOS14.

Comment: it is probably to do with the ios, because I have an older iPad, but with ios15, and it works well. I can see the "liveController.message" going crazy, but the TabView is responsive, just like nothing is happening.

Comment: Thanks for a throttling example. Any suggestions if throttling is not an option?

Comment: I don't see how throttling should not work in this case? You can always write to a separate publisher and subscribe with throttling. But you will have to add an indirection with a component like the `UpdateEmittingComponent`.

What is creating these rapid updates? Might be easier to reason with more details.

Comment: @mgratzer the app really needs to update the state 30 times/sec. My particular use case is drawing a sequence of images that are generated on the fly at 30 fps.