# Broken animation with variable height in a LazyVStack inside a ScrollView

Tags: swiftui

Info: XCode Version 15.0 & Targeting iOS 15

If there is changing height in one of adaptor view in swiftUI `LazyVStack` inside `ScrollView`, the animation will be broken

For example, in this code i found that if i scroll down just a little bit until the rectangle disappear and turn the toggle, the animation will be jitter

Found very similar problem with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68459594/content-with-variable-height-in-a-lazyvstack-inside-a-scrollview-causes-stutteri)

```
       VStack {
            Toggle(isOn.description, isOn: $isOn.animation())
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(height: self.isOn ? 200 : 50)
                    ForEach(0..<100) { index in
                        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/200/300")!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The interesting thing is if i change `LazyVStack` into `VStack` it run smoothly. Here is the result

[LazyVStack](https://youtube.com/shorts/jtfwEABjt8Y) VS
[VStack](https://youtube.com/shorts/tWlyqZiblnQ)

Comment: Cannot reproduce on iOS 16.4, so probably just a bug.

Comment: It is equivalent with `LazyVStack { ... }.animation(.easeIn, value: isOn)`

Comment: @Sweeper i'v been update the video example link

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: im having weird animation bugs also, take  a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78209143/weird-animation-bug-inside-scrollview-with-lazyhstack