# Weird animation bug inside scrollview with lazyhstack

Tags: animation, swiftui, scrollview, lazyhstack

I have a ForEach of itemView() inside a lazyHStack which is inside a Scrollview,

In the itemView,  I have a a tap gesture that adds an item to an array and then runs a checkIfSelected() func, which compares if the item is selected, if so, you see a checkmark and changes the background of the view and adds an outline as you can see.

The other part is the %Discount Badge as you can see for some items, that are in discount, the problem is as you can see the discount badge is kinda flying around when scrolling and then sets where it goes. im using .transition and .animation, this doesn't happen of course with the checkmark as its always there and just the .opacity is changed to 0, but as im using .transition(.move(.top)
) on the discount badge, it animates correctly accordingly when the checkmark appears you see it coming from the top down and viceversa when the checkmark is not present.

I have tried different approaches but no luck.

```swift
VStack(spacing:5) {
    LinearGradient.defaultOrangeRedGradient
        .mask(Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        ).background( Circle().fill(Color.white).frame(width:20,height:20))
        .opacity(isSelected ? 1 : 0)
        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        .zIndex(4)

    
      
   
    
   if( item.isOffer) {
        VStack {
        Image( colorScheme == .dark ? item.isOfferIconDark : item.isOfferIcon)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width:20,height:20)
            .opacity(item.isOffer ? 1 : 0)
            //.transition(.opacity)
        }.transition(.move(edge: .top))
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2))
                .zIndex(2)
        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: well, If I use a HStack instead of a lazyHStack , the bug doesn't happen, I see the problem is by using lazy which recreates the element inside as needed. So while creating the element it is doing my checkup for the badge, while as scrolling; as soon it goes out of the screen, it is doing the same computation and creating the element as is coming from the right... so the badge identity is kinda recreated and messing up as, while scrolling it takes some time to go sit where it needs to go

Comment: in my case I have 3 sections with items, and the number is fixed to 20, I will be doing tests now on instruments to check on performance, if you had infinite columns ( elements ) a normal Stack wouldn't be good as the memory will fill in quickly

Comment: using lazyHStack ram starts at 90 in that view, and the max it goes is 130mb and no more, while using normal HStack it loads everything right away and ram eats up to 175mb